# how to update the bunch values when condition meets from python when inserting into mysql

Tags: mysql-python, insert-update

I need to insert a record from python into mysql, at the same time, if the birthday is equal to '9999-11-11', like below picture,
[image]

then the birthday needs to be updated with the new birthday. The code is as below:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO client
            (full_name, first_name, last_name, birthday, diagnose)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,%s) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            birthday = IF(birthday='9999-11-11', %s, birthday);
```

The problem is: with `birthday = IF(birthday='9999-11-11', %s, birthday)` how can I refer to the %s is new birthday?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the insert logic? I'm assuming that you have a bunch of data on your python code, then for each entry you need to update on the mysql following your rule. I'm confused because you mentioned python lists on the question title, but your code does not have any

Comment: Thank you. You are right. There is no list, just a bunch of data.

Comment: I think I might have found the solution like below:"""INSERT IGNORE INTO client
            (full_name, first_name, last_name, birthday, diagnose)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,%s) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            birthday = IF(birthday='9999-11-11', %s, birthday); """,(full_name, first_name, last_name, birthday, diagnose,birthday)